# Pass props by click Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the list of items and when i am clicking on one of them, i should pass props by click. But somehow props are undefined in the target component

```
<v-card // target component
  v-for="product in myProducts" // loop through array
  :key="product.id" // binding key
  :current="currentProduct" // passing props
>

<v-btn
  :to="'/product/' + product.id"
  @click="getCurrent(product)" // get current product 
>Open</v-btn>

data(){
  return{
    currentProduct: {} // here i pass current product
  }
}

methods:{
  getCurrent(item){ // click handler
    this.currentProduct = item //setting current item
  }
}

/// target component
props: ['id', 'current']
```

What am i doing wrong? Maybe at the moment, i clicked, the current item is not in the currentProduct?

Comment: i understood that you have many cards in your page and you want when you click a button it redirects you to the product details

Comment: You are wright.

Comment: @SashaZoria I don't see a closing tag for <v-card>?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am facing a similar.